# Tools to extract all functions from a source code project

Tags: c++, c, parsing

I'm trying to build a list of available tools for parsing a complete source code package and extracting all of the functions/methods as separate pieces.  My goal is to run a tool or script, immediately know how many functions are in the package, and to easily examine the complete set of segmented functions one-by-one as needed.

Right now I'm using the NiCad clone detection tool, which includes an extract script written in TXL (a tree transformation language).  Each function is pulled out and stored as a unique entity in an XML document, so handling the list of functions is very convenient.  NiCad included extract tools for C, Java, and Python.  I'm mostly concerned with C, but it's also nice to have the rest available.  We don't have a C++ parser set up yet - that would be handy.

I've also used Doxygen, which has the added bonus of identifying the call graph.  There's a lot of markup in these files though, so it's a bit of extra work to parse Doxygen's output to get them into a plain list of functions.

Has anyone used a tool that extracts the full set of functions/methods?  Do you have recommendations or warnings?  If you've written your own, is it available somewhere?

Thanks!

Comment: In my humble opinion, in a well written C or C++ codebase, you should be able to see this and all other relevant information about how the project works at a glance by examining the header files.

Comment: I referenced Doxygen in the question, and it certainly works fine.  I'm interested in other options that are available.  For example, I'd like to know if there are parsers that give me the option of including/excluding comments.  It would be really helpful for me to build up a list of these tools.  Thanks!

Comment: libclang looks really helpful, I'll check it out.  And Wug, it seems as though not all developers seem to follow good practices all of the time.  It would be useful to have tools that work even when the project is not so neatly organized.

Comment: Do you need list of function declarations only (I mean without bodies)? Then consider `ctags`…

Comment: `gccxml` may also work for you, though it's overkill.  It supports C++.

Comment: For the type of work I'm doing, the function bodies are also important, so ctags might not fit.  Thanks for the gccxml recommendation - it looks like they don't include the function bodies either?

Comment: GCCXML does not produce function bodies.

Answer (score -1):

You can use nm tool of linux. "nm is used to list symbols from object files". See man page of nm to get more details; The sample nm is copied here for your reference.

```
void fun1() {
    return;
}

void fun() {
     fun1();
}
int main()
{
     fun();
     return 0;
}
```

Nm of the above program on running "nm a.out | grep T"

```
08048470 T __libc_csu_fini
08048400 T __libc_csu_init
080484ac T _fini
080482b8 T _init
08048320 T _start
080483d9 T fun
080483d4 T fun1
080483e3 T main
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think this is addressing the problem.  I want more than just the basic symbols.